# is there a way for google charts to append into one div?

Tags: google-visualization

when the user clicks the button, a chart will be created.. this code is just cloning the main chart.. since the main chart changes, the user can click on several the main chart several times. currently it will delete the previous chart when the button is clicked again..

when a button is clicked, the getChart function will be called and the original chart will be cloned into the trial div. But since the original chart can change thus the user can add multiple cloned different type of charts into the trial div?

```
 function getChart() {
      google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper, 'ready', onReady);
          function onReady() {
            google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper.getChart(), 'click');
          }
        var trialChart = wrapper.clone();
        trialChart.setContainerId('trial');
        trialChart.draw();
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the wording of your question does not present the problem very well. I see what you have, but what is the expected result, and how does current result differ from what you expect? I don't quite understand how the title relates to the rest of the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might be what you're looking for...

the clone is added to the *trial* div,
rather than replacing the chart in the *trial* div

so each chart is saved when the clone button is pushed

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', '2015');
    data.addColumn('number', '2016');
    data.addRows([
       [new Date('01/01/2016'), 200, 210],
       [new Date('01/02/2016'), 190, 220],
       [new Date('01/03/2016'), 205, 200],
       [new Date('01/04/2016'), 220, 230],
       [new Date('01/05/2016'), 212, 210],
       [new Date('01/06/2016'), 185, 193],
       [new Date('01/07/2016'), 196, 207]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'LineChart',
      containerId: 'chart_orig',
      dataTable: data,
      options: {
        height: 400
      }
    });

    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      document.getElementById('cloneBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var trialChart = chart.clone();
        var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_trial').appendChild(document.createElement('DIV'));
        chartDiv.id = 'div-' + (new Date()).getTime();
        trialChart.setContainerId(chartDiv.id);
        trialChart.draw();
      }, false);
    });

    chart.draw();
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="cloneBtn" value="Clone" />
<div>Original Chart</div>
<div id="chart_orig"></div>
<div>Trial Chart</div>
<div id="chart_trial"></div>
```